# Time Delay In Android

Tags: android, multithreading, time, sleep, delay

So I am trying to create a "strobe" light effect in my app.

To do this I need a time delay, one of 100ms the other of 20.

Here is the code I'm using.

```
Thread timer = new Thread();
    long longTime = 100;
    long shortTime = 20;
    for (int x = 0; x < 2000000; x++)
    {
        layout.setBackgroundColor(background);
        try {
            timer.sleep(longTime);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        layout.setBackgroundColor(backgroundBlack);
        try {
            timer.sleep(shortTime);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The issue I have is that when I click the button to call that code, nothing happens. So I've done a bit of debugging and am pretty sure it is the timing call. I have never programmed in Java before so I am unsure how to call a Thread Sleep.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a Handler as below to achieve this.

```
public class Strobe extends Activity {

    private LinearLayout mLinearLayout;

    private Handler mHander = new Handler();

    private boolean mActive = false;
    private boolean mSwap = true;   

    private final Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {

        public void run() {         
            if (mActive) {
                if (mSwap) {                    
                    mLinearLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                    mSwap = false;
                    mHander.postDelayed(mRunnable, 20);
                } else {
                    mLinearLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                    mSwap = true;
                    mHander.postDelayed(mRunnable, 100);
                }
            }           
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.strobe);
        startStrobe();
    }

    private void startStrobe() {        
        mActive = true;
        mHander.post(mRunnable);
    }
}
```

Set a Theme to the Activity to make it full screen.

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

Comment: I changed the findViewByID(R.id.strobe); in your code to linearLayout because that is what it is called, pasted that in and changed the android:onClick to "Strobe". After all that is done, I run it and click the button and it force closes.

Comment: What does logcat say? Feel free to checkout the entire eclipse project from here http://www.assembla.com/code/rochdev-android/subversion/nodes/ExampleStrobe

Comment: When I debug it, Eclipse is telling me the Thread is suspended because it threw an IllegalStateException

Answer (score 1):

I think this article would benefit you.
http://oreilly.com/catalog/expjava/excerpt/index.html
specifically this
http://oreilly.com/catalog/expjava/excerpt/index.html#EXJ-CH-6-FIG-1

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are not running in the Thread. In order to run code in the thread you must override it's run() method. Based on your current code, the following may capture what you want to do.

```
Thread timer = new Thread(){
    public void run(){
        long longTime = 100;
        long shortTime = 20;
        for (int x = 0; x < 2000000; x++)
        {
            layout.setBackgroundColor(background);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(longTime);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            layout.setBackgroundColor(backgroundBlack);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(shortTime);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

timer.start();
```

However, threads don't play that well with the Android OS. For your application, it may be better to use Android services. See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html .

Comment: That fixes the issue, it sets the background to white but it never changes after that.

Comment: After I added the start, it changes the background to white, then force closes.

Comment: Yeah, like I said, threads can be problematic in Android. Try using services instead.